# 'public' folder ignored either in docker, Github actions or Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker, next.js, github-actions, acr

I have a Next.js project which I'm creating a docker image from, and then publishing to Azure Container Registry via Github Actions.

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:12.3.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN ["npm", "install"]
RUN ["npm", "run", "test:ci"]
RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

So it's not that complicated. Just to mention that early I've also tried `COPY . .`

My intent is to copy everything in the CWD to the `/app` folder. This includes several files and directories, including a folder called `public` which contains a couple of static files.

When I build it locally it copies everything including the `public` folder. When I run this through Github Actions and push it to Azure Container Registry, everything is kept, except the `public` folder.

Just to mention, I tried copying the `public` folder naming it something random and then pushing both the `public` folder and the copied one. The pipeline ran successfully and the image was published to ACR.
I then pulled the newly pushed image down locally and everything was there including the random folder except the `public` folder!

For clarity I checked that running `docker run -it -p 3000:80 <registry-name>.azurecr.io/<image-name>:<tag> sh` after pulling it, and then `ls -la`.

So, somewhere along the line the `public` folder is filtered out. Next.js has a convention that forces me to name this folder 'public'.

Relevant Github Actions lines:

```
jobs:
  build-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build and push image
        run: |
          docker login $ACR_NAME -u $ACR_USER -p $ACR_PASSWORD
          docker build . --tag "$ACR_NAME/$REPO_NAME:latest" --tag "$ACR_NAME/$REPO_NAME:${{github.run_number}}"
          docker push $ACR_NAME/$REPO_NAME:${{github.run_number}}
```

I've tried google'ing, but either I'm using the wrong search terms or there hasn't been anyone running into this yet.

What's going on? The `Dockerfile` seems to be working (based on local results). I feel the one to "blame" here is Github Actions that's where the image is built when it goes wrong, but I don't know.

Comment: So is the `public` folder checked into git? can you show the output of `git ls-files`

Comment: Oh man. I hadn't updated `.gitignore` since refactoring the project from a purely frontend one, to a Next.js project. So no it wasn't checked in.

I was thinking who's to blame here. And per usual, it was me. Thanks for telling me the obvious, I needed that

Comment: it happens. Glad that helped